# How to create an element without hardcoding the name

Tags: xslt

I tried this but it does not seem to be valid syntax.

```
<xsl:element name="$myElementName"></xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to surround it with `{}` to ensure the value is evaluated rather than used as a verbatim string, e.g.

```
<xsl:element name="{$myElementName}"></xsl:element>
```